# expandable upwards div creating empty space below

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have added some jQuery to expand my div vertically, however it's creating a space below itself the same type of height the expandable container is. Need this to be removed.

The div in question is the one attached to the footer. Content is "ABOUT PENDLEY MANOR". If there is also a way to decrease the div back to how it was before expanded would be helpful.

Live URL: http://bit.ly/1fIuBqa

HTML

```
<div class="index-about-expandable" id="index-about-expand-container">
            <h2>ABOUT PENDLEY MANOR</h2> <a><i class="fa fa-plus index-expand-plus" id="expand"></i></a>
            <div class="clearboth"></div>
            <p>this is a test</p>
        </div>
```

JQUERY

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $("#expand").click(function() {
                    $("#index-about-expand-container").animate({'height': '270px', 'top': "-220px"});
                });
            });
        </script>
```

CSS

```
#index .index-about-expandable { background-color: #433131; padding: 1px 10px; color: #fff; width: 240px; margin-top: 27px; position: relative; z-index: 5; overflow: hidden; height: 45px; }
#index .index-about-expandable i { font-size: 14px; float: left; margin-top: 15px; }
#index .index-about-expandable h2 { float: left; margin-right: 20px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by relative positioning. It frequently gives me some big headaches and I usually try to avoid it.

I suggest moving the div#expand into the footer. If the footer is not relatively positioned, then give #expand a wrapping container with a relative position.

Then, position #expand as absolute with a negative Top property and an appropriate value.

For your javascript, you'll need to additionally modify the top property when you modify the height.

Cheers.

Comment: There's no need for this element on all pages so can't have it in the footer, only needed to appear on this homepage. Will look into it based on your suggestion though too thanks.

Comment: Well if this site is dynamic you can certainly have a template rule controlling when this is shown. At the very least a css class rule for each page would let you hide the element.

Good luck!